# C# VS2008 show editor to select a collection of existing controls at design time

Tags: c#, user-controls, design-time, collectioneditor, uitypeeditor

I have the next property on my user control:

```
[
    Browsable(true),
    Category("Data"),
    Description("Listado de controles que proporcionan los parámetros para generar el reporte."),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)
]
public List<Control> ControlesParametros { set; get; }
```

I want to make Visual Studio to show me a editor where I can select some of the existing control instances in the form where I have placed my user control. Currently Visual Studio shows me an editor where I can add new controls, but not select the existing one.

I have found a similar question and answer, but the solution was a custom editor designed using .NET Framework 4.0, and I currently have 3.5:
[Design-time editor support for controls collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372691/design-time-editor-support-for-controls-collection)

Is there a native editor, or should I build one?

Comment: There's nothing new in .NET 4 that affects the validity of that answer.

Comment: There are some classes used in that answer that are not present in .NET Framework 3.5. One of these is System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would use `Collection<Control>` instead of `List<T>`. A list will often work, but it does expose your collection in ways you may not want.

To get the existing controls, you need to dig into `context.Container.Components` in the `LoadValues` override.  It will have *everything* including the host form itself and components, so you will likely have to filter them.  One thing for certain is to remove components (like `DataGridViewColumns` and `TabPages`) as they wont go into a List or Collection of controls; other things like TableLayoutPanels you will often want to remove also.

This version filters out some components and controls for the default dropdown:

```
protected override void LoadValues(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{

    bool bAdd = true;
    Control thisCtl = null;

    Collection<Control> tCollection = (Collection<Control>)value;

    foreach (object obj in context.Container.Components) {
        //Cycle through the components owned by the form in the designer
        bAdd = true;

        // exclude other components - this weeds out DataGridViewColumns which
        // can only be used by a DataGridView
        if (obj is Control) {
            thisCtl = (Control)obj;

            if (ExcludeForm) {
                bAdd = !(thisCtl is Form);
            }

            // custom exclude list 
            if ((typeExclude != null) && (typeExclude.Count > 0)) {
                if (typeExclude.Contains(thisCtl.GetType)) {
                    bAdd = false;
                }
            }

            bool bCheck = false;
            int ndx = 0;
            if (bAdd) {
                bCheck = tCollection.Contains(thisCtl);

                ndx = myCtl.Items.Add(new ListItem(thisCtl));
                myCtl.SetItemChecked(ndx, bCheck);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

If you prefer, you can display the eligible controls Dialog style and use a CheckedListBox for the user to pick controls.  There is an article on CodeProject [Selecting Form's Controls at Design Time](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687430/Selecting-Forms-Controls-at-Design-Time) which goes into more detail.

It is in VB, but allows you to easily implement such a beast pretty easily (I wrote it, so I may be biased):

```
ExampleDropDownControlCollectionUIEditor : ControlCollectionDropDownUIEditor
{
    public ExampleDropDownControlCollectionUIEditor() : base()
    {
        base.ExcludeForm = true;

        base.CheckControlWidth = 200;

        base.typeExclude.Add(typeof(RadioButton));
        base.typeExclude.Add(typeof(Label));
    }
}
```

The dialog form is as simple, just using a different base class, `ControlCollectionDialogUIEditor`

Comment: yes, I know this is an old question, I just kind of like UI Editors and saw this was still unanswered.

Comment: Many thanks @Plutonix, I almost lost hope to get an answer for this question :'( I'll try it :)